# Bind a number with a left padding of zeros as a String using SQLiteStatement

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Surprisingly, I've just realised that SQLiteStatement can't properly bind a number with a left padding of zeros as a String.

Example:

```
SQLiteStatement insertSqlStatement = 
    db.compileStatement("INSERT INTO table(column) VALUES(?)");
insertSqlStatement.bindString(0, "00012");
insertSqlStatement.executeInsert();
// "12" is inserted, instead of "00012"
```

This doesn't work:

```
insertSqlStatement.bindString(0, "'00012'");
// "'12'" is inserted
```

This leads to an error:

```
db.compileStatement("INSERT INTO table(column) VALUES('?')");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your issue, asssuming the "error" is the loss of the 0's, is a misunderstanding of how **SQLite** minimises the amount of data stored.

How that data is stored, it's **storage class**, is affected by the column's type (aka **affinity**). In short if the column does not have a type affinity of TEXT or BLOB then it will have a numerical type affinity and store the number in the smallest form so dropping the numerically useless 0's.

If you need to store the 0's then ideally you should utilise a column with a type affinity of TEXT which means that the column should be declared as anything that contains **TEXT**, **CHAR** or **CLOB** but does not contain **INT** or **INTEGER**.

as per :-

> **3.1. Determination Of Column Affinity**
>
> The affinity of a column is determined by the declared type of the column, according to the
> following rules in the order shown:
>
> 1. If the declared type contains the string "INT" then it is assigned
>    INTEGER affinity.
> 2. If the declared type of the column contains any of the strings "CHAR",
>    "CLOB", or "TEXT" then that column has TEXT affinity. Notice that the
>    type VARCHAR contains the string "CHAR" and is thus assigned TEXT
>    affinity.
> 3. If the declared type for a column contains the string "BLOB" or if no
>    type is specified then the column has affinity BLOB.
> 4. If the declared type for a column contains any of the strings "REAL",
>    "FLOA", or "DOUB" then the column has REAL affinity.
> 5. Otherwise, the affinity is NUMERIC.
>
> ***Note that the order of the rules for determining column affinity is
> important. A column whose declared type is "CHARINT" will match both
> rules 1 and 2 but the first rule takes precedence and so the column
> affinity will be INTEGER.***

You should have a look at [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Comment: You are TOTALLY right, thank you very much! I was using "STRING" instead of "TEXT" on the "CREATE TABLE" sentences. Thanks again!!